# Clang 3.8 C++ - reading all the source files in a directory using LibTooling

Tags: c++, clang++

EDIT: I am using Linux Fedora 22.

I am using Clang 3.8 LibTooling lib to read Cpp source files, parse the AST and then do some processing on the data I extract. When I invoke my tool using command line on a single file or multiple files given as input, everything works.

But if there are tens or hundreds of files, it becomes infeasible to write all of them again and again. So, is there a way to counter it? For example, I dump all the source files names in a txt file and give it as input to the tool hoping that command line parser of Clang will read the files from given paths, or some other way?

For example this works fine:

```
toolname f1.cpp f2.cpp --
```

But how to do this without giving all filenames:

```
toolname f1.cpp .......f1000.cpp --
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give information about operating system, as it's important piece.

Assuming you're on linux try following:

```
toolname $(find directory -name "*.cpp") --
```

where directory is path to directory with files you want to process.

$(...) is linux's shell syntax. It launches what is between parenthesis and - after its done - replaces whole $(...) text with launched command's standard output. *find* is linux command, which searches directory (and its subdirectories) for files matching given criteria (in an exmaple only *-name* is given - file's name, ignoring directory, must match *.cpp pattern). So assuming directory will be */home/q* and there're going to be three files:

```
/home/q/a.cpp
/home/q/a.h 
/home/q/b.cpp
```

launching

```
toolname $(find /home/q -name "*.cpp") --
```

will launch subcommand

```
find /home/q -name "*.cpp"
```

this will output

```
/home/q/a.cpp
/home/q/b.cpp
```

(*a.h* will be ignored as it doesnt match *-name* pattern) and this will be put back into original command:

```
toolname /home/a.cpp /home/b.cpp --
```

In case of windows you can use python script, for example:

```
import os, sys, subprocess

toolname = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])
args = [toolname]
for name in os.listdir(path):
  if name.endswith('.cpp'):
    args.append(os.path.join(path, name))
sys.exit(subprocess.call(args))
```

where first argument would be path to tool and second path to directory with files (not recursive).

Comment: Really sorry for not providing the OS info. Yes, I am using linux. Thanks. I will try it and post an update.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much for the help! :)